# redis and db save new document row strategy

Tags: database, redis, primary-key

I think it is standart situation.

Client send new document row.
Server get it , gen guid and put row into hash set. With key uid:oiu:guid.
Send row guid to client.
So on client dataset with keys (1,2,3,guid)
On this stage new row not stored into db and not have real PK.
After that client decides to del or edit new row.
It send to server received guid of row.
Server find key uid:oiu:guid. And update or del it.
All good.

Other situation . Server after received new row and put it to hashset uid:oiu:guid save it to db async.
After successfully saving server rename or del and create new key uid:oiu:real_pk
After that client send request to del object with guid. But this key not exist in redis. Instead of him key uid:oiu:real_pk

I think to maintain list in redis with guid:real_pk pairs. So if client send request to del or edit with guid and server not found hashset uid:oiu:guid it try to find conformity of guid to real pk in list. If find - continue to work with key uid:oiu:real_pk

So. Is it “good” strategy ?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an *eventual consistency* approach to storing your documents. In such an approach you would generally avoid renaming your documents in any asynchronous way. (Your document names are your uid:oui:guid and uid:oui:real_pk items.)

To solve this problem you'll store the uid:oui:guid name in the your persistent database along with the document. You can then access the document using the name you first generated. I guess your real_pk values are the consecutive sequence numbers generated by your RDBMS when you insert new rows into a table.

The primary purpose of globally unique identifiers (GUIDs) is to allow you to assign unique names to objects without having to check that they are unique. A secondary purpose is to assign hard-to-guess names to slow down cybercriminals (UUIDV4 are the hardest to guess, and sequence numbers are notoriously easy to guess).

So, don't change the original names of documents after you tell clients about them. Instead store those names with the documents and index your database table so those names can be fast to look up.

An added benefit: if your documents are unchangeable and have unchangeable names, you can put them into caches in any way you wish without confusion.

Comment: i think it is not good idea to have private and foreign keys in RDBMS as guid (char(36)). for perf issue. instead of int

Comment: another way i see to have additional hash key for counters for every objects(private keys). in this case i not gen guid. but get next counter for object from this hash key. send it to user and after save data from redis to db in background.

Comment: I think you mean *primary* keys, not *private* keys. For what it's worth, some RDBMSs use so-called "clustered indexes" -- that use the primary key's index -- to store the data in the table. (For example, SQL Server. MySQL/InnoDB). Those RDBMSs perform best with sequential (autoincrementing) primary keys. But there's no performance problem at all with non-primary indexes of columns containing GUID values. It's a very common use case.